# links crashing iOS Music app

Tags: ios, swift, itunes-store

I'm trying to open a link to a track from my iOS app but the Music app randomly crashes.

I get the track URL via the iTunes [search API](https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/#searchexamples).

Here's an example trackURL extracted from the JSON response: https://itunes.apple.com/us/album/10-bagatelles-op.-5-bagatelle/id253254038?i=253254078&uo=4&partnerId=11

I add my affiliate id (&at=MYID) and the media type (&mt=1) for music, along with &app=music to open in Apple Music rather than iTunes (which would be &app=itunes).
I've tried it without the &at and &mt params and it still crashes. I've pasted the link into Safari (and Chrome) and it's a valid link; I see the appropriate page.

To actually open the URL, I use

```
UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
```

I've tried this way also:

```
let svc = SFSafariViewController(url: URL, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
svc.delegate = self
self.present(svc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Sometimes everything works - the Music app opens, and goes to the track. It plays just fine. Then I go back to my app, try another link. and Music crashes. My app is still running. There is a crash log for Music. It says the problem is "attempted to retain deallocated object". I don't know what I personally can do about that.

Any suggestions welcome.

```
Process:             Music [1100]
Path:                /Applications/Music.app/Music
Identifier:          com.apple.Music
Version:             1.0 (3.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.apple.Music [577]
OS Version:          iPhone OS 10.2 (14C92)
Report Version:      104
Exception Type:  EXC_BREAKPOINT (SIGTRAP)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x00000001abd62c88
Termination Signal: Trace/BPT trap: 5
Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x5
Terminating Process: exc handler [0]
Triggered by Thread:  0
Application Specific Information:
attempted to retain deallocated object
```

I don't think I'm trying anything unusual. In fact, I think this is probably a common use-case for the iTunes search API.

XCode 8.2.1, Swift 3, iOS 10.2, iPhone 6S+ also running iOS 10.2

Comment: Here is a simple Github repo that displays the problem: https://github.com/genedelisa/LinkToMusic

Answer (score 2):

From the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2151/_index.html):

> Trace Trap [EXC_BREAKPOINT // SIGTRAP]
>
> Swift code will terminate with this exception type if an unexpected condition is encountered at runtime such as:
>
> a non-optional type with a nil value
> a failed forced type conversion

Seems to me there is an error parsing your url. Are you able to share that part?

Comment: The exception is in the Music app, not my app. The URL i use is fine - I've tried it in Safari and it works. An example URL is in my post.